# Pergunta com contexto amplo mas fornece bom conhecimento, como proceder?

Tags: debate

Bom pessoal, tudo que eu sei sobre programação, aprendi na internet, especialmente com uso de github e stackoverflow(pt.stackoverflow) e sei que o uso do mesmo é para fins mais específicos.

Muitas vezes nos deparamos com boas perguntas mas que são fechadas/excluídas por estarem em um contexto amplo ou baseada em opiniões, padrões de preferência pessoal, etc...

Uma das minhas dúvidas, e vontade de contribuir para com a comunidade - que me ajudou tanto, se enquadraria em um contexto semelhante, imagino eu. Então antes de tentar elaborar a questão, gostaria de saber a opinião de vocês.

A questão que tenho, e que ainda não encontrei uma boa referência em português, seria sobre um guia de boas práticas para desenvolvimento de CSS (css/sass) no âmbito de web sites, web apps, etc... Como não encontrei nenhum material que reúna essas informações para uma abordagem mais prática, resolvi criar um projeto no github, [você pode vê-lo aqui](https://github.com/celsomtrindade/CSS-Style-Guide), para fornecer material para aqueles que tem dúvidas semelhantes, porém amplas.

Por exemplo: Quando usar um pseudo-element ou pseudo class? Qual seria uma boa estrutura para um projeto SASS? Qual a melhor convenção para nomenclatura de classes?

O projeto em si aborda diversas áreas que eu gostaria de explorar pouco a pouco e obter mais informações para alimentar ainda mais o projeto e ajudar ainda mais as pessoas.

Mas, por se tornar amplo, como posso trazê-lo para o pt.stackoverflow visando a melhoria do seu conteúdo e disponibilizar mais informações para as pessoas? Seria melhor abordar pequenos pontos do projeto com referência ao mesmo? Ou tentar uma abordagem mais geral? O que me dizem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acho que a solução está na sua própria pergunta. Você está pensando em fazer um

> guia de boas práticas para desenvolvimento de CSS

E esse guia é constituido de

> Quando usar um pseudo-element ou pseudo class? Qual seria uma boa estrutura para um projeto SASS? Qual a melhor convenção para nomenclatura de classes?

Este não é um site para publicar um Guia, mas com certeza pode-se aproveitar todas as vantagens que ele oferece para avançar capítulo a capítulo apresentando cada questão como um problema real que está enfrentando.

A precaução principal é não ter que ouvir "por favor, publique esse tipo de coisas no seu próprio blog" ou ter a pergunta fechada como "muito ampla" e eventualmente deletada.

Muitas vezes já cheguei a soluções bem legais que dariam ótimas respostas no SO, mas esqueci completamente qual era o problema inicial. Então posso escrever o resultado com detalhes, mas preciso inventar o motivo que deu origem a tudo, o que produz uma pergunta pobre/mediocre e uma resposta boa.

Uma idéia de como publicar esse tipo de coisa aqui:

*Em vez de*

> Qual seria uma boa estrutura para um projeto SASS?

*talvez*

> **Pergunta:** Conflito *tal* ao fazer estrutura SASS *tal*
>
> `{explicar e mostrar aquele erro de iniciante ao trabalhar com essas estruturas}`
>
> **Resposta**: seu capítulo do seu guia :)
>
> **Surpresa**: outras respostas mais legais que a sua
>
> **Possibilidades**: marcar sua resposta como Wiki Comunitário autorizando que o conteúdo seja gerenciado pela comunidade; fazer um "guia" de Melhores Respostas SASS na [**Wiki de Tag**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/sass/info) ou no seu site/repositório
>
> **Probabilidade**: outras perguntas com títulos diferentes e contextos diferentes cuja solução é a mesma --> *duplicata*

<sub>**Observações importantes**:</sub>

<sup>- se participar ativamente do site, em algum momento terá medalha de ouro na Tag [tal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tal), o que dá direito a fechar unilateralmente uma pergunta como duplicata de outra dentro dessa tag. Ou seja, se alguém faz uma pergunta "como fazer Xyz" ou "como fazer Xwv", você pode fechar como duplicata de "como fazer X".</sup>

<sup>- conferir a [**política de auto-promoção**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) aqui do site.</sup>

Comment: fui conferir o que era a tag [tag:tal]... :V